# How do you make two planes look as one surface?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, objects

[image: Rendered Picture] 
Above is the rendered image of two planes merged as one. I am trying to make them look as one surface and not two. Although they are merge, you can see that it has two very different appearances. Both have the same material. How do I make it so that it looks as it is one surface?

Comment: Are your normals okay? Try selecting all and hitting ctrl+N in edit mode (this recalculated normals).

Comment: please provide a blend file

Comment: Why not just delete one of the planes?